# Cannot create a capped collection larger than 500 Megabytes

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using a Mongo db on 32bit system and I need to create a large capped collection with a max size of 1GB. Everything works fine on 64bit system, but on 32bit I'm getting the error:

```
com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command failed [command failed [create] { 
"serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , 
"errmsg" : "exception: assertion db\\pdfile.cpp:437" , 
"code" : 0 , 
"ok" : 0.0}
```

The total storage size for the server is 2GB on 32bit system, but even with this size I can't create a collection larger than 500MB. What does this magic number mean?

Mongo db server version is 2.0.6

**Additional info:**

I have a couple of database files, the total size of which is `34MB`. Before running a mongo db, I'm copying those files into the 'data' directory, starting Mongo db and then in shell I see the same number for the totat size - `35651584 (34MB)` (the command used is taken from the comments below). If I try to create a collection of size 500MB I see a new file added (512MB). But if for example I will try to create a collection of size 600MB, I have an error discribed above (but the 512MB file still added).

[The Mongo db server log](https://gist.github.com/3274176)

The Mongo db is started with the command line options:

```
> db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
{
        "argv" : [
                "mongod.exe",
                "--dbpath",
                "..\\data",
                "-vvvvvv",
                "--logpath",
                "..\\log\\server.log"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
                "dbpath" : "..\\data",
                "logpath" : "..\\log\\server.log",
                "vvvvvv" : true
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
>
```

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6202  , this shouldnt happen with 2.0.6

Comment: @DhruvPathak are you sure that this is the same problem? (even though the same line is mentioned 'db/pdfile.cpp:437')?

Comment: No, I am not sure. Just wanted to make sure that you are using version 2.0.6 .

Comment: @SurikovPavel: What O/S are you using .. and how big is your data directory (in mongo shell try: `db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand({listDatabases : 1}).totalSize`).  Suspect you are hitting the total limit of mapped files for a 32-bit MongoDB server.

Comment: @Stennie I'm testing by copying initial database files into the data directory. Before creating a capped collection, the totalSize command shows me '35651584'. OS - Windows Server 2008 Datacenter, 32bit

Comment: @SurikovPavel - Why are you running a 32-bit installation?  I mean its not like you don't have the license to run a 64-bit installation they used the same license.

Comment: @Ramhound If I was the only user there would be no problems (or the system was new)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB [runs much better](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations) on a 64-bit system, can you change to x64? As Stennie said you're must likely hitting a mmap limit due to other data in your database.

Can you test this hypothesis by connecting with the mongo shell and trying to create a new by running a new collection that is 1 byte larger than 512 MB -

```
db.createCollection("mycoll6", {capped:true, size:536870913})
```

You should hopefully get the following error message -

```
"errmsg" : "exception: can't map file memory - mongo requires 64 bit build for larger datasets",
```

In the Mongo shell, connect to the admin database and view the size of your database to see how much data you have -

```
use admin
show dbs
```

Update: based on some additional testing (I used Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit), this seems like it could be a bug.

**Ubuntu Testing**

> db.createCollection("my13", {capped:true, size:536608768})
>   {
>       "errmsg" : "exception: assertion db/pdfile.cpp:437",
>       "code" : 0,
>       "ok" : 0
>   }
>   db.createCollection("my13", {capped:true, size:536608767})
>   { "ok" : 1 }`

536608767 bytes is a little under 512 MB, leaving room for some sort of header in the file.

I thought it was maybe related to `[smallfiles][2]` as all 32-bit installs run with that option, however, an x64 build with the `smallfiles` does not display the same symptoms.

I have logged [SERVER-6722](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6722) for this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I have only 34MB of data before creating a capped collection. I've seen this error 'exception: can't map file memory' when there were already 4 files of size 512MB. However I don't have so many files before running a command, so I think I'm facing a different problem.

Comment: @SurikovPavel: can you try enabling [verbose logging](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging) eg `-vvvvvv` and capture the log output just before and when you run the `db.createCollection()`?  If you can share on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or similar, the log output might reveal more specific details.

Comment: @Stennie I've added a log file for creating a 600MB collection

Comment: @SurikovPavel: Thanks .. the assertion looks helpful: `Assertion failure approxSize <= Extent::maxSize() db\pdfile.cpp 437`.  Are you running with any other command line options (perhaps `--smallfiles`)?  Can you share output of `db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")`?

Comment: @SurikovPavel: looks like a bug, I've logged a SERVER ticket for further investigation.

Comment: @SurikovPavel No worries, if you're happy with the answer, can you accept it?